# Xdebug 3: hide function parameters from call stack

Tags: php, xdebug

Since upgrading to Xdebug 3, I have a problem with my debug output.

After the error message there is the "call stack". The stack is made of function calls, and for each function call each parameter is dumped in its entirety. If you have objects and the objects get even a bit complex, this renders each frame a huge mess of useless data, and the debug gets enormous.

Is it possible to disable the dump of functions parameters in the call stack?

Here is my config:

```
xdebug.mode=debug,develop
xdebug.client_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=MYIDE
xdebug.show_local_vars = 0
xdebug.collect_params = 0
#xdebug.var_display_max_data = 128    // no visible effect
#xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 0     // works with side effects on var_dump
xdebug.collect_params = 0
```

The only thing that worked so far is to set `xdebug.var_display_max_depth` to 0. But then any explicit `var_dump()` will be useless, because that setting influences both.

Here I highlighted the part I'd like to hide:
[image]

Comment: There is currently no way to turn this of, and the `xdebug.collect_params` setting has been removed in Xdebug 3.

Comment: I have this same problem. My template wrapper sometimes has huge snippets of HTML code as an argument value so then tons of extra HTML get rendered into the page causing me all kinds of grief. I really hope they add a way to disable this, or at the very least give us the option to escape any HTML characters in variable data so that  the code is printed instead of rendered......

Answer (score 0):

I needed a quick fix, therefore I just... styled it away.

```
.xdebug-error tr td:nth-child(4) span {
    max-width: 35rem;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

This is just a workaround. If someone has a better solution, please answer!

Comment: Thanks for this idea, I've looked at the whole code (see https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug/blob/ab2af3fae9b3cc00802ca1c5ad6b90980a46b180/src/develop/stack.c#L130), and you can't at the moment (May 2022). Filtering with https://xdebug.org/docs/develop#trace-filter would filter the whole line, not only the parameters. I've tried using the `error_prepend_string` to include your CSS, but it doesn't seem to work either (Xdebug doesn't use it, even if I can see it a bit in the code)